# Copying selected files in multiple folders to different destination in Ubuntu

Tags: copy

I have the folder path in LINUX (Ubuntu) as follows:

```
/data/nldas/raw/hourly/
```

in the hourly folder I have sub-folders from 1979 to 2016 and in each year folder I have julian day folders from 1 to 365/366. In each julian day folder, I need to copy `NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb` files to a different destination in LINUX path e.g. `/datadg/name/soil`. I do not want the same folder structure in the destination path.

Can somebody help me to do in LINUX please?

Thanks in advance.

```
Error:

\name@lin-v01:/$ find /datadg/RND_Data/ldas/raw/hourly/ -type f -name 'NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb \ -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=/datadg/rndFS/name/soilM
find /datadg/RND_Data/ldas/raw/hourly/ -type f -name 'NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb \ -print | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=/datadg/rndFS/name/soilM
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name `NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb \\ -print | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=/datadg/rndFS/name/soilM\nfind /datadg/RND_Data/ldas/raw/hourly/ -type f -name NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb \\ -print | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=/datadg/rndFS/name/soilM\nfind /datadg/RND_Data/ldas/raw/hourly/ -type f -name NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb''.
find: paths must precede expression:  -print
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
cp: missing file operand
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

Comment: I used the backslash to show that the command was continued after the line break. Either remove the backslash or break the line after the backslash, or see my revised answer

Answer (score 1):

Read, and re-read `man find`. 
Read, and re-read `man xargs` `find` and `xargs` are the answer:

```
find /data/nldas/raw/hourly/ -type f -name 'NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb' -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=/datag/name/soil
```

Note if there are two `NLDAS_VIC0125_H.*.grb` files with the SAME name (the '*' is the same in both cases), one will be overwritten in the target directory, unless you use the `--backup=numbered` option to `cp`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your method but got an error: See the above question for the error.